# Java - quick way of assigning array values to individual variables

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, variable-assignment

I have a method which will return two strings in an array, `split(str, ":", 2)` to be precise.

Is there a quicker way in java to assign the two values in the array to string variables than

```
String[] strings = str.split(":", 2);
String string1 = strings[0];
String string2 = strings[1];
```

For example is there a syntax like

```
String<string1, string2> = str.split(":", 2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind immediately. However, I wonder what the need is to assign it to these names, and if you couldn't set it up with two functions. The first function could get the first part of the String, and the second the second part of the String. Is there a reason to do this beyond clarity?

Comment: Nope, no reason beyond clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no such syntax in Java.

However, some other languages have such syntax.  Examples include Python's tuple unpacking, and pattern matching in many functional languages.  For example, in Python you can write

```
 string1, string2 = text.split(':', 2)
 # Use string1 and string2
```

or in F# you can write

```
 match text.Split([| ':' |], 2) with
 | [string1, string2] -> (* Some code that uses string1 and string2 *)
 | _ -> (* Throw an exception or otherwise handle the case of text having no colon *)
```

Comment: In PHP you can do `list($foo,$bar,$baz) = array("fred","barney","wilma");` and get back foo="fred", bar="barney", etc. Handy for split functions with columnar data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a holder class  :

```
public class Holder<L, R> {
    private L left;
    private R right;

   // create a constructor with left and right
}
```

Then you can do :

```
Holder<String, String> holder = new Holder(strings[0], strings[1]);
```

Answer (score -6):

I can say "Use Loops". May be for loops, may be while, that depends on you. If you do so, you don't have to worry about the array size. Once you have passed the array size as the "termination condition" it will work smoothly.

UPDATE:

I will use a code like below. I didn't runt it anyway, but I use this style always.

String[] strings = str.split(":", 2);

```
List keepStrings = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
{
    String string = strings[i];

    keepStrings.add(string);


}
```