# Java: instanciate variables from array

Tags: java, arrays, assign

In Python you can do the following:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b, c, d = myList
print a # -> 1
print d # -> 4
```

Is there a way to do such a thing in Java? Better/faster than below:

```
int[] myList= {1, 2, 3, 4};
int a = myList[0];
int b = myList[1];
int c = myList[2];
int d = myList[3];
```

Comment: No. Java doesn't have this mechanism.

Comment: you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328327/java-quick-way-of-assigning-array-values-to-individual-variables

Comment: nope, not possible in short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the same but you can get close to it by using comma operator:

```
int[] myList= {1, 2, 3, 4};
int a = myList[0], b = myList[1], c = myList[2], d = myList[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList of type Integer.

This would look like the following code:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then you can set variables by using .set(int where, int what)

```
myList.set(0,1);
```

Or you can just append with .add(int what)

```
myList.add(2);
```

Then you can get the variables by using .get(int where)

```
int a = myList.get(0);
int b = myList.get(1);
```

This sets variable a to 1 and variable b to 2, because you append it at the very end. The advantage of those ArrayLists are, that you can get variables more easy than with Array, but you need a litte bit more code to add it. So its good for a big pool of non-changing variables in your code.

Comment: *"you can get variables more easy than with Array"* ... how is `int a = myList.get(0);` "more easy" than `int a = myList[0];`? And btw `myList.set(0,1);` won't work if there is no index **0**.