# Set each variable in a group of variables to each item in an array

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

In Python, I could say something like `a, b, c = someArray`, and `a` would be set to `someArray[0]`, `b` would be set to `someArray[1]`, and `c` would be set to `someArray[2]`.

Is there any equivalent syntax in Java for quickly assigning variables to values in an array?

Comment: No. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328327/java-quick-way-of-assigning-array-values-to-individual-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has no comparable syntax, unfortunately. Only a single variable at a time can be used as an l-value in Java.

Comment: Dammit. Individual assignment it is, then