# Idiomatic way to assign values from an array to individual variables

Tags: kotlin

There is an array of length 4

```
var foo: String? // These variable declarations are out of your control
var foo2: String? // they are part of a bean and an api contract
var foo3: String?
var foo4: String?

var bars: Array<String> = Array(NUMBER_OF_BARS) { "" }

foo = bars[0]
foo2 = bars[1]
foo3 = bars[2]
foo4 = bars[3] // <- Invalid
```

Any numbers except 0, 1 and 2 in the code result in a
MagicNumber complaint by static code checker and is not allowed.

Basically this question but for kotlin, [Java - quick way of assigning array values to individual variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328327/java-quick-way-of-assigning-array-values-to-individual-variables)

How is that written idiomatically given the restraints? I tried naming the indexes as the static code checker hints I should do, but it's not that nice to be honest:

```
const val BAR_1 = 0
const val BAR_2 = 1
const val BAR_3 = 2
const val BAR_4 = 3
```

That's no fun

Comment: What if you put {foo, foo2, foo3, foo4} in an array, and iterate it along with `bars` setting foos one-by-one?

Comment: @hugo I don't see it. Immutability of strings makes it even harder

Comment: Immutab... oh right. I'm dumb, apologies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array is `bars` then Kotlin allows you to do

```
var (foo, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5) = bars
```

Make sure you aren't trying to create more variables than the array contains though. That will cause an exception. If you aren't creating new variables, then this approach won't work. But the good news is, the above statement is basically just syntactic sugar for using the `componentN` methods, so you can just use them directly.

```
foo = bars.component1()
foo2 = bars.component2()
foo3 = bars.component3()
foo4 = bars.component4()
```

A bit more verbose than just using indices, but it will get your static code checker to shut up.

Comment: Ahh nice answer! Not sure It fits though, will edit my question to better reflect my situation

Comment: Hmm that syntax can be used to get rid of the magicNumber though, if you use temporary variables. Maybe that is the way to go? Not the most concise ever, but maybe better than alternative